# Sending HTML Email using Mailgun API with RestSharp C# causing message to be truncated at ampersand "&" when included

Tags: c#, api, html-email, restsharp, mailgun

Below is the code I am currently running in a console app to test. The email is sent successfully.

But the body is truncated and you only see `This is test HTML` without `& rest of message`. I can workaround by replacing `&` with and but this does not work where I need to embed `urls` in emails with query string parameters.

I have tried html encoding without any luck.

```
var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
client.Authenticator = new RestSharp.HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "{APIKEY}");

RestSharp.IRestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/{DOMAIN}/messages", RestSharp.Method.POST);

string MailBody = "<html>This is test HTML & rest of message</html>";

request.AddParameter("from", "{EmailAddress}");
request.AddParameter("h:Reply-To", "{EmailAddress}");
request.AddParameter("to", "{EmailAddress}");
request.AddParameter("subject", "Mailgun Test New");

request.AddParameter("html", MailBody);

try
{
    RestSharp.IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What did you replace the & with? Was it "&amp;"?

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the & with

```
&amp;
```

in the text and it worked.
In links I just kept the & as is and it worked to.

```
string MailBody = "<html><body>This is test HTML &amp; rest of message. <a href=\"http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d\">Link with querystring</a></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was was with the version of the RestSharp full I was using. I updated the project to use the latest and everything worked as expected.